# Datepicker in JQuery Mobile is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm a newbie to Jquery mobile, and i added a date picker in to my view

I added the plugins and my code is

```
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
 <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css"rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../docs/_assets/css/jqm-docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>  
<script>

 $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = true;
 });    
 </script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jQuery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>

 </head>
```

Is there any error on this?

I follow this tutorial,
    http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: try adding your `mobileinit` code at last.

Comment: @Arun.. there is no error in console..i tired with firebug

Comment: @rps..were i want to place tat.. please refer above tutorial.. as per tat i placed the stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On comparing your code with the [view source: of mobile datepicker link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/).

### You have just copied the code from their source

They have these below files in their folder, *which can't be accessed by you*

```
<script src="jQuery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>
```

Download these files to your local machine and access it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path to these files" />
```

Comment: +1, :) also suggest OP to download them and add it to the project.

Comment: @Joyal for jQuery UI datepicker, http://jqueryui.com/download/ and for jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js,https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/source/browse/trunk/com.mds.apg/resources/jqm/demo2/experiments/ui-datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js?r=92

Answer (score 0):

Am doing this code for asp.net websites

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#From_date").datepicker({ dateformat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val()
    }
);
```

Comment: Actually this is not OP's problem.