# jquery mobile datepicker not work with augularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, mobile, datepicker

I am following jquery mobile datepicker widget link [http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/datepicker/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322675/datepicker-in-jquery-mobile-is-not-working) to build my page. The datepicker works but I found if I use it together with augular, by selecting the date in the datepicker, it won't update the scope in augular.
Please see the jsfiddle I built in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lizhou/16v06vst/1/)

You can observe that if you type into the textbox, scope change is reflected. However,by selecting the date in the datepicker, it won't update the scope.

Any idea?

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TodoCtrl" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        StartDate:{{startdate}}
        <input name="mydate" type="text" data-role="date" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="startdate" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining jQuery datepicker with angular is not as easy as simply adding ng-model. See this article: http://www.grobmeier.de/angular-js-binding-to-jquery-ui-datepicker-example-07092012.html

I've used the angular bootstrap datepicker in the past if you are looking for a simple solution: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/